# JUnit test isolated routes

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am creating a Camel application. I have a series of routes that are all connected via direct channels. So...

- `RouteA` reads from `direct:1` and writes to `direct:2`
- `RouteB` reads from `direct:2` and writes to `direct:3`
- `RouteC` reads from `direct:3` and writes to `direct:4`

I am using the Java DSL to create the routes. The context is created inside Spring and the routes use references to beans in the Spring context.

My question, what is the best way to test each route in isolation. I can create each route in a seperate `RouteBuilder` but the context in the spring would contain all three route builders so that would not work.

One thought would be to put all the Spring beans in one context file and then use test-specific context files that only load a single `RouteBuilder`. The issue with this is that there is a possibility for copy / paste error if there are other things set up in the `camelContext` in the configuration file (error handlers, interceptors, etc).

Would there be a way to create a default camel context, link the spring application context and load a single `RouteBuilder`? This has the same issue as test-specific xml files but at least doesn't have extra xml files.

Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just need to black box test each route, then just use Camel's [AdviceWith](http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html) support to isolate the input/output of each route...

in particular look at the interceptSendToEndpoint() API...should allow you to intercept the sending of messages between the routes and assert on the expected output, etc.